# finding missing numbers from array using O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

We have an array of numbers from 1 to 100. Two numbers are missing. Finding those two numbers using O(n) time and O(1) space. Noted that those numbers in the array are not sorted.
example :
let there be an array [4, *missing*, 1, *missing*, 2]
As you can see, the missing is 3 and 5. Assuming that the array of numbers from 1 to 5 and two number is missing. Actually, it is [4, 1, 2] Without 3 and 5.

so, i dont know how to solve this. could someone of you help me? my programming language is c++. here is the array:

> {24, 44, 19, 92, 1, 18, 28, 50, 88, 5, 52, 11, 76, 39, 82, 85, 65, 93, 98, 4, 72, 94, 45, 59, 48, 46, 47, 67, 87, 99, 14, 70, 80, 25, 20, 22, 21, 41, 77, 73, 2, 13, 36, 6, 27, 81, 29, 62, 8, 35, 32, 49, 10, 100, 90, 78, 30, 34, 51, 9, 43, 58, 26, 33, 64, 15, 17, 57, 12, 56, 61, 79, 75, 97, 84, 42, 55, 83, 91, 86, 38, 89, 96, 74, 23, 7, 68, 60, 16, 66, 69, 53, 3, 71, 37, 63, 54, 95}

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have already made an honest attempt post the code and point out where you are having problems. If you haven't tried anything then this question is off-topic and you should put some effort into solving the problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: What's the question ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sort your array, iterate over the array fields, compare to a counter `i` you increment at every step, if `i` is different from the field `push_back(i)` in a vector.

Comment: Sorting is not O(n).

Comment: I would upvote Oberon's comment but I ran out of up arrows to give.

Comment: @Oberon: Since it is known that the range [1 .. _n_] matches to the number of fields of the array `A[n]`, the time complexity with swaps will not exceed O(_n_): `for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { while(A[A[i-1]-1] != A[i-1]) { swap(A[A[i-1]-1], A[i-1]); } }`

Comment: @TheOtherGuy: O(k * n) is O(n) for all constants k.